# How to achieve linking of wmi classes using c++?

Tags: c++, wmi

I have a sample code as below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace WMIIRQ
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach(ManagementObject Memory in new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                "select * from Win32_DeviceMemoryAddress").Get())
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Address=" + Memory["Name"]);
                // associate Memory addresses  with Pnp Devices
                foreach(ManagementObject Pnp in new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                    "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DeviceMemoryAddress.StartingAddress='" + Memory["StartingAddress"] + "'} WHERE RESULTCLASS  = Win32_PnPEntity").Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  Pnp Device =" + Pnp["Caption"]);

                    // associate Pnp Devices with IRQ
                    foreach(ManagementObject IRQ in new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                        "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID='" + Pnp["PNPDeviceID"] + "'} WHERE RESULTCLASS  = Win32_IRQResource").Get())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("    IRQ=" + IRQ["Name"]);
                    }
                }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not familiar with c#, i got this code from some link, I need some methods in c++ so that i can do the exact operation as above mentioned in the code. I searched a lot but i couldn't exactly what i needed. Could someone suggest me the method to get it. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are very comprehensive documents from Microsoft on how to do this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(v=vs.85).aspx).

You basically have to use COM to spin up all the object types you need, invoke the queries, then clean up explicitly at the end. It's messy, but it works.